# SQL WHERE NOT EXISTS query not returning results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, impala

I'm having trouble constrsucting a query and getting it to run on impala. I created the following working query to join two tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM illuminavariant as vcf, ensembl_genes as ens 
WHERE vcf.filter = "PASS" 
AND vcf.qual > 100 
AND vcf.chromosome = ens.chromosome
AND vcf.position BETWEEN ens.start AND ens.stop
```

Now I'm trying to write a query that finds all variants WHERE vcf.filter = "PASS" and vcf.qual > 100, but do not have a match by chromosome and position.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM p7dev.illumina_test, p7dev.ensembl_test
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM p7dev.illumina_test as vcf, p7dev.ensembl_test as ens
  WHERE vcf.chromosome = ens.chromosome  
  AND vcf.position BETWEEN ens.start AND ens.stop  
 )
```

But that's not returning any results. I think a WITH clause might do the trick, but I'd really appreciate if anybody could help me wrap my head around the logic of how that would work. Thanks so much!

Comment: Which platform are you using? MySql or Sql Server?  Please just tag one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking for variants that are not correlated to any ensemble, it seems strange that you would form a cross join of variants and ensembles from which to filter out rows.  If that's really what you want, though, then this ought to do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM illuminavariant as vcf, ensembl_genes as ens 
WHERE vcf.filter = "PASS" 
AND vcf.qual > 100 
AND (
    vcf.chromosome != ens.chromosome
    OR vcf.position < ens.start
    OR vcf.position > ens.stop
  )
```

That just negates the condition correlating variant rows with ensemble rows.

I suspect what you really want is more like this, though:

```
SELECT vcf.*
FROM
  illuminavariant as vcf
  LEFT JOIN ensembl_genes as ens 
    ON vcf.chromosome = ens.chromosome
    AND vcf.position BETWEEN ens.start AND ens.stop
WHERE
  vcf.filter = "PASS" 
  AND vcf.qual > 100
  AND ens.chromosome IS NULL
```

That performs the same join as your first query, but as a left join.  The rows that actually represent matches are then filtered out by the `ens.chromosome IS NULL` condition.  It returns only the columns of the variant table, as the whole point is to find variants that have no corresponding row in the ensemble table.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM p7dev.illumina_test vcf
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                  FROM p7dev.ensembl_test as ens
                  WHERE vcf.chromosome = ens.chromosome  
                  AND vcf.position BETWEEN ens.start AND ens.stop
                 )
AND vcf.filter = 'PASS' 
AND vcf.qual > 100
```

Comment: Thank you very much; it's a very clear and working query. I marked the other response as the answer because he also explained how and why the query worked.